# how to filter with certain condition and apply a function at the same time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
text,                  pred                 score                             logits
No thank you.          positive    [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], , [1, 0, 0]]]   [0.01, 0.02, 0.97]      
They didn't respond me negative    [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]                [0.81, 0.10, 0.18]
```

in which you can use this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['No thank you', 'They didnt respond me negative'],
                   'pred':['positive', 'negative'],
                   'score':['[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2],[1, 0, 0]]]', '[[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]'],
                   'logits':['[0.01, 0.02, 0.97]', '[0.81, 0.10, 0.18]']})
```

What I need to do is:

if the `df['pred'] = 'positive'` I want to sum all the elements in the first position of the `score` on that row `sum(df['score'][0])` which is `(0+1+1)` and multiple by third element of `logits` `df['logits'][2]` which is`(0.97)`.

(We will do the same thing for the `negative` just change the position:
`sum(df['score'][1])` which is `1+0+0+0` and multiple by first element of `logits` which is `df['logits'][1]` which is `0.81`

So the output would look like this:

```
text,                  pred                 score                       logits          decision
No thank you.          positive    [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]  [0.01, 0.02, 0.97]  1.94    
They didn't respond me negative    [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]            [0.81, 0.10, 0.18]  0.81
```

What I have done (or the logic I need to follow) and Obviously my code does not run and I guess the problem is here `sum(df['score'][0])`.

```
df[df['pred'] == 'positive','decision'] = df[df['pred'] == 'positive', df['logits'][2] * sum(df['score'][0])]
```

***for more clarity***

in score we have one list associated to each word. that's why three list in first row and 4 list in second row. And they are nothing but (positive, negative, neutral) score associated to each word. if the list empty we replace it with zero in the calculations.

Comment: please provide your dataframe as dictionary: `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] without it the chances of anyone answering is very low. Reproducing your `df` is tedious and error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create mapping-dictionaries with various rules (e.g. if positive, sum only first index (`0`) etc.):

```py
m_sum = {"positive": 0, "negative": 1}
m_mul = {"positive": 2, "negative": 0}

df["decision"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: sum(v[m_sum[x["pred"]]] for v in x["score"] if v)
    * x["logits"][m_mul[x["pred"]]],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                    text,      pred                              score              logits  decision
0           No thank you.  positive  [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]  [0.01, 0.02, 0.97]      1.94
1  They didn't respond me  negative            [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]   [0.81, 0.1, 0.18]      0.81
```

---

EDIT: with `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "text": ["No thank you", "They didnt respond me negative"],
        "pred": ["positive", "negative"],
        "score": [
            "[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2],[1, 0, 0]]",
            "[[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]",
        ],
        "logits": ["[0.01, 0.02, 0.97]", "[0.81, 0.10, 0.18]"],
    }
)


df["score"] = df["score"].apply(literal_eval)
df["logits"] = df["logits"].apply(literal_eval)

m_sum = {"positive": 0, "negative": 1}
m_mul = {"positive": 2, "negative": 0}


df["decision"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: sum(v[m_sum[x["pred"]]] for v in x["score"] if v)
    * x["logits"][m_mul[x["pred"]]],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                             text      pred                              score              logits  decision
0                    No thank you  positive  [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]  [0.01, 0.02, 0.97]      1.94
1  They didnt respond me negative  negative            [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]   [0.81, 0.1, 0.18]      0.81
```

Comment: thanks so much. I will need to this is awesome solution. but it raises this error for me `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`. what wondering do yo have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @sariii Are the values of `score` column lists-of-lists? If the are strings, you need to convert them to correct types.

Comment: Im sorry, my bad. yes they are like this `"[[], [], [], [], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [], [], []]"`

Comment: @sariii Then apply `ast.literal_eval` on the string first - to convert them to list-of-lists.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have meeting right now I will check it after the meeting and will update. Again thanks a loot

Comment: I fixed that and now its not string anymore but still raises the same error (previously also I was using the one in the correct format (without string) as when I saved my df to csv it was saving as the string and I was using the version before saving which did not have string included). Its in this for `[[], [], [], [], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [], [], []]` but raises the same error. I have updated my question with a dictionary of df so its easier to try. Also, if we can do it for `positive` and `negative` separately for the sake of simplicity is still good.

Comment: @sariii The string `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [], [], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]` is fine. The error must be in other string.

Comment: Hi Andrej Kesely, do you have any idea of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214498/how-to-use-count-over-2d-list-in-pandas . Thanks!