# How to use count over 2d list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['No thank you', 'They didnt respond me'],
                   'pred':['positive', 'negative'],
                   'score':["[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]", "[[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]"] 
                   })
```

(Its a string but we can convert it to list this way `from ast import literal_eval.   df["score"] = df["score"].apply(literal_eval)`)

which looks like this:

```
text,                  pred                 score                            
No thank you.          positive    [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], , [1, 0, 0]]]      
They didn't respond me negative    [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]
```

The `score` is a 2d list, in which the first element is for `positive` second element for `negative` and third element `neutral`.

What I want is if the `pred=positive` count the number of list in the `score` that are `non zero and non empty`. The same logic for `negative` and `neutral`.

So the result will look like this:

```
text,                  pred                 score                        count                         
No thank you.          positive    [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]]      2  
They didn't respond me negative    [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]                 1
```

because in the first row the `pred=positive` and two elements in the first position of `score` are non empty non zero, and the same applies to `negative`.

What I have done so far:

```
m_sum = {"positive": 0, "negative": 1, "neutral": 2}
df["count"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: count(v[m_sum[x["pred"]]] for v in x["score"] if v and v!=0),
    axis=1)
```

But cannot use `count` this way.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a list at all. It's a string

Comment: I have added the code to convert string to list

Comment: literal_eval is imported from the ast package?

Comment: Yes I am adding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum()` to count number of non-zero elements:

```py
# if not converted already, convert the "score" column to list:
# from ast import literal_eval
# df["score"] = df["score"].apply(literal_eval)

m_sum = {"positive": 0, "negative": 1, "neutral": 2}

df["count"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: sum(v[m_sum[x["pred"]]] != 0 for v in x["score"] if v),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                    text      pred                              score  count
0           No thank you  positive  [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]      2
1  They didnt respond me  negative            [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace '[]' by '[0, 0, 0]' and compute the sum and get the right column according 'pred' column:

```
get_cnt = lambda x: np.sum(ast.literal_eval(x['score']), axis=0)[m_sum[x['pred']]]

df['count'] = df.replace({'score': {r'\[\]': '[0, 0, 0]'}}, regex=True) \
                .apply(get_cnt, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                    text      pred                              score  count
0           No thank you  positive  [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]      2
1  They didnt respond me  negative            [[], [0, 1, 0], [], []]      1
```